# shell script function always shows globurl=noglob urlglobber when I open the terminal

Tags: function, shell, unix, oh-my-zsh

Probably is answered but I've been checking on the internet for a while and I cannot figure it out why is happening.

I have this function in shell

```
alias google= function google(){
        if [[ -n "$@" ]] 
        then
                echo "you typed $1"

        fi
}
```

Right now I'm testing. I want to create my own google search on the terminal. The code is working, but each time that I open the terminal, always it comes up with this message:

```
you typed globurl=noglob urlglobber
```

Why is showing me this always? Am I missing some step? I'm not used to working a lot with shell code so probably is something really silly

BTW, I'm working with ZSH

Comment: What I want is just type google on my terminal and then execute this function. Without alias I'll not be able to invoke it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Cause of error

The reason you get this message is, that you are actually overriding the builtin `alias` with your function. `zsh` allows to create functions with multiple names simply by giving multiple names before `()`. For example:

```
foo bar baz () {
    echo $0 $@
}
```

This defines three (identical) functions named `foo`, `bar` and `baz`. When you run your code snippet:

```
alias google= function google(){
  # [...]
}
```

You also defined three functions: `alias`, `google=` and `google`. `function` is not overridden, because it is a `zsh` reserved word, but neither does it work as a command as it is not in the first place.

So the following (or very similar) line in your configuration does not actually define an alias by running the *builtin* `alias`:

```
alias globurl="noglob urlglobber"
```

Instead the *function* `alias` is run with `globurl="noglob urlglobber"` as the first parameter.

#### Solution

You do not need an alias, when creating a function. Try this instead:

```
function google () {
    if [[ -n "$@" ]] 
    then
        echo "you typed $1"
    fi
}
```